# Arquivo Global.asax não carrega

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho um projeto em Webforms e queria fazer rotas nele.

Segui uma resposta que me deram em outro tópico e tudo funcionou muito bem, porém agora fui criar outro projeto e parece que não reconhece as rotas que eu criei.

Meu arquivo está assim:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">
        public class Global_asax : System.Web.HttpApplication {
            void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
                DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControl.CallbackError += new EventHandler(Application_Error);
                RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);
            }

            void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) {
                // Code that runs on application shutdown
            }

            void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) {
                // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
            }

            void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
                // Code that runs when a new session is started
            }

            void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) {
                // Code that runs when a session ends. 
                // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
                // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
                // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.
            }

            public static void RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes)
            {
                routes.MapPageRoute("Inicio",
                "Inicio",
                "~/inicio.aspx");

            }
        }
</script>
```

O que pode estar acontecendo?

Answer (score 1):

O problema foi resolvido adicionando uma classe Global.cs com o código do Global.asax, e mantendo o Global.asax apenas com a primeira linha.